# Replace-recording for MIDI in Logic Pro

Tags: midi, logic-pro

I'd like to be able to do the following:

1. Set recording quantization to 1/8
2. Loop an 8-beat region
3. Keep replace-recording until I like the tune

[image]

This breaks my creative flow.

I've tried every combination of the overlapping recording + the replace button to no avail. Please help, or tell me if it isn't possible with MIDI in Logic.

Comment: After not being able to achieve this replace-recording workflow, someone recommended trying the Maschine; and I can happily report that that was exactly what I was looking for. So, for anyone interested in additive recording in a way that doesn't break your flow—check it out. [Although I'll still leave this question open, it has been solved for me.]

Comment: If you found an acceptable answer, you might consider adding it yourself, and accepting it as _the_ answer.  You can always change which answer is _accepted_ later if a better solution shows up.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can find the answer to your problems in Settings > Recording > MIDI > Overlapping Recordings....

or take a look at this part of the LogicPro Manual: [Midi Take Recording](http://documentation.apple.com/en/logicpro/usermanual/index.html#chapter=14&section=19&tasks=true)

Hope this helps

Comment: unfortunately Take Recording for MIDI (unlike it's audio counterpart) is an all or nothing proposition. You can choose between takes, but not combine two or three together. The other disadvantage is that you can't merge to a previous take while recording a new one [which is what I'm ultimately trying to do].

Answer (score 2):

Right click the record button in the arrange window
Select "Record Settings"
Select "Recording" from the top menu
Under Midi select the "Overlapping Recordings" Menu
Select "Create tracks in cycle record"

This will create a new track with the previous loop on it every time a new pass is made.

The first pass appears as normal, the second pass appears to be on the first, but at the end of this pass the a new track is created with the first loop on it, and so on....

All newly created tracks play while recording.

Comment: This still produces the result of my 3rd image, but on different tracks. I still hear the sound of the note I'm overlapping, and I'd like not to hear it.

Comment: There should be another option within that menu to mute the previous pass. I'll confirm when I get to my laptop this afternoon

Comment: Yes, the bottom option in the same menu does what you need: "Create tracks and mute in Cycle record"

Comment: Mal, still not it. That mutes the whole last track, vs muting just the piece that I played over.

Comment: OK, I get what you're after now. I'm not sure that's possible. I'd use the first loop method I suggested then arrange then after you're finished recording arrange the various loops how you want them, then merge the lot back to one track. I don't think there's another way. Maybe if you feed the recorded MIDI back into the channel you could achieve this.

Comment: You'll need to get down and dirty with the environment to pull that off though. I haven't used the environment like that in some time, so I can't help there I'm afraid. If I get a chance I'll take a look, but it might not be for a few days - even then I'm not sure I'll remember enough to pull it off

Answer (score 2):

Use the Replace button next to cycle record.[image]